# jQuery validate skipping the second input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've got three form fields, two inputs and one textarea. When I hit the submit button before entering any data my browser says the first input field and the textarea must be entered, but the second input field is ignored. Does anyone got an idea how I should fix this?

Posted the code on http://jsfiddle.net/D5tk4/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input fields have `id` attributes but not `name` attributes. Inputs need to have name attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/D5tk4/2/